# Magnolia CMS, Content app, naming a node from a property

Tags: magnolia

I have a content app with a dominating unique field that I would like to use as the node name for new nodes. The problem is that it contains characters that cannot be part of a JCR node name, and thus if I were to link it to jcrName rather than a custom property it will get mutated into something that isn't useful for the fields original purpose (among others, the field value will contain slashes).

My current solution adds an additional field for the node name, and while this certainly works, it adds a UI field to the detail for no reason that is apparent to the users of the app.

Is there a way to have a field that reads and writes a string value to a custom property, yet that is also used (in its clened form) to name the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this](http://pvnp.us/CustomSaveAction.pdf) as a base, paying special attention to the code in 2.b.ii. (especially setNodeName), and ignoring the yaml bits.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You might wanna use info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeNameHelper#getValidatedName (removing illegal chars) and NodeNameHelper#getUniqueName (avoiding duplications) when setting a custom node name.