# Java JCR is it possible to add '&' into node name

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

If I'm renaming node in JCR, is it possible to add `&` to that name? Currently when I pass string name for ex: `test & node` it is saved as `test---node`./

Answer (score 2):

The naming restrictions are [documented here](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/constraints.html):

> The JCR specification already restricts what can go into the “local” part of an item name - see JCR v2.0 Specification, Section 3.2. In particular:
>
> - Characters not allowed in XML are forbidden in names as well; this affects most control characters plus unpaired surrogates; see Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition), Section 2.2.
> - Furthermore, the names `.` and `..` can not be used.
> - Finally, the characters `/`, `:`, `[`, `]`, `|`, and `*` are forbidden. For these, the JCR v2.0 Specification, Section 3.2.5.4 proposes a mapping to “private-use” code points.

so as `&` is XML special character is not allowed without prior escaping to the entity (`&amp;`).

Comment: I found query that defines my current problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424289/magnolia-cms-content-app-naming-a-node-from-a-property/78120232#78120232, so workaround for me is creating new field called lets say category, instead of using jcrName, but how can i use category for name of a new Node and have it as separate field inside that node.